# Python Selenium Beautifulsoup pdf

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to make a program that downloads pdfs after I've done a search. The web is an aspx and with selenium I can enter the information in the fields correctly:

```
input_user=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@name="ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_93bc4c3a_0f69_4097_bed1_978c8b545335$freetext"]')
textolibre="jamaica"
input_user.send_keys(textolibre)
```

but the page that returns the results is the same (aspx) and I can't download the pdfs.

I would like to be able to enter the fields in the form without selenium opening a browser. I tried with PhantomJS but it says:

```
UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
```

And when you return the results, I can download them, considering that the url doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

While using PhantomJS just add 2 extra lines to your code

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Or else if you are using gekodriver for the firefox browser you can use this in your code

```
opts = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
opts.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts, executable_path='Your gekdriver exe path')
```

If you could share a more detailed complete code i could help you more effeciently

Comment: `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")` was helpful.

Comment: always happy to help